# NDVI Analysis of a small area from the year 2000- 2011

Tags: data, remote-sensing, ndvi

I want to perform an NDVI analysis in a small area. I want to see the change around a river body for the year 2002, 2005, 2008, 2010 and 2011. I tried using Landsat-7 data but due to the scanline error, it's not a good choice.

I want to work on free data for now.

Which satellite data should I use?

Comment: Where is your area of interest?

Comment: The lhasa river in Tibet

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to use Landsat, then Landsat 5 ran until 2013 (when Landsat 8 was launched). This imagery doesn't suffer from the scan-line error and would cover your time period of interest.